# how to get the current location in the map surface - slick 2D

Tags: java, slick

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(int oldx, int oldy, int newx, int newy) {
  super.mouseMoved(oldx, oldy, newx, newy); 
}
```

we can get the mouse location in this method via newx, newy . i want to know is there any such way to get the location in slick2D? when we press the arrow keys and move a image of a man on the game surface(tile map)?

Comment: This looks similar to your [other question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16180/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-when-using-slick-2d-library). Are you asking something different and does the answer to the other question not answer this?

Comment: yes i'm asking different thing here, other question is sounds similar though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing some concepts..... If you use your **keyboard** to move your player, then you usually store the location of the player's position in the player's object.

If you use your **mouse** to move the player, then you use the location of the mouse on the screen to set the player's position on the game.

So, there is no such thing as *location of keyboard* as there is for *location of mouse pointer*.

In any case, whichever way you update the location of your player, his position is still stored in the object. I.e.

```
class Sprite {
    Point position;
    Texture texture;
}

class Level implements MouseListener, KeyListener {
    Sprite player;
    ...
    void update(...) {
        // THIS IS THE POSITION OF YOUR PLAYER  
        //whether you updated it with mouse or keybaord
        Point position = player.getPosition(); 

        // Do something with this...
    }

    // Update player position using mouse
    public void mouseMoved(int oldx, int oldy, int newx, int newy) {
        player.setPosition(new Point(newx, newy);
    }

    // Update player position using keyboard
    public void keyPressed(int key, char c) {
        if (key == Input.KEY_W) {
            player.getPosition().X += 1;
        } else if (key == Input.KEY_S) {
            player.getPosition().X -= 1;
        } else if (key == Input.KEY_A) {
            player.getPoisition().Y -= 1;
        } else if (key == Input.KEY_D) {
            player.getPosition().Y += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped clear some things...